# problems with location manager in maps api v2 android

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-maps-v2, currentlocation

i'm developping an android app which shows in a map the current location for the user.

Few hours later, i have discovered the error, locationManager doesn't actualize the location.

I put the code relative a locationManager:

```
mapa = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapaTapas)).getMap();

String serviceString = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService (serviceString);
String proovedor1 = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(proovedor1);
String proovedor2 = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(proovedor2);

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(proovedor1, 5000, 5, new LocationListener()
{
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1,Bundle arg2) { }

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location Location)
   {
       location=Location;
   }
});

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(proovedor2, 5000, 5, new LocationListener()
{
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1,Bundle arg2) { }

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location Location)
{
    location=Location;
    }
});

location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(towers);

    if(location != null){

        glat = location.getLatitude();
        glon = location.getLongitude();

        Log.i("location", "latitud: "+glat);
        Log.i("location", "latitud: "+glon);

}

cp = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(glat, glon))
        .zoom(15)
        .build();     
    mapa.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cp));
```

i need to save in glat and glon the current value of the location and the if it's posibble implement some method to refresh it automatically

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to manually request location updates from `LocationManager` now that `OnMyLocationChangeListener` interface was [introduced](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/releases).

You only need to enable the my-location layer (`map.setMyLocationEnabled(true)`), set the listener (`map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this)`) and do whatever you want with the current location (e.g. animate camera) passed back to you in the corresponding callback (provided by implementing that interface).